# Return subclass type from parent class function

Tags: c#

I want to have a parent class that contains a chainable function (a function that returns `this`) which should, in each child class, return an object of the type of the child class, not the parent class:

```
class ParentClass<T> where T : ParentClass<T> {
    public T ChainableFn()
    {
        ...
        return (T)this;
    }
}

class ChildClass : ParentClass<ChildClass> {

}



ChildClass child = new ChildClass().ChainableFn().ChainableFn().ChainableFn();
```

This does not work because `ParentClass<T>` cannot be cast to `T`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Seems to...

Comment: In the case of `new ChildClass()` then the instance is actually a `T`, but what if you just do this: `new ParentClass<ChildClass>()`? Then `this` is actually just a `ParentClass<ChildClass>` and not a `ChildClass`. The compiler is unable to determine that this would be safe **precisely because it isn't**. There is no guarantee that `this` is `T`.

Comment: Have you considered using extension methods instead? As Lasse noted, `T` is not the same as `ParentClass<T>`.

Comment: Your code does work.  Certainly does for me.  What version of C# are you using?

Comment: Yep, works fine, tested in .NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0.

Comment: The problem begins with more levels of inheritance.

Comment: Why not use a wrapper like a `Chainable<T>` that wraps the type to make chainable?